# How to make dynamic kml from java

Tags: java, xml, kml

I am new to KML I have to make a KML file that contains some information about a place and that data should be displayed in Google map. I have written a code in java which will generate  a KML as an output but I have some problem, the KML is not generating.
*java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\PlaceMarkers.kml (Access is denied)* this is my error..
This is what I have done so far..

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.Result;
    import javax.xml.transform.Source;
    import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
    import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Element;

   public class GenKMLPlaceMarker {

public int id;
public String name;
public String address;
public float lat;
public float lng;
public String type;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    GenKMLPlaceMarker KML = new GenKMLPlaceMarker();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homeland";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("kml");
        root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1");
        doc.appendChild(root);
        Element dnode = doc.createElement("Document");
        root.appendChild(dnode);
        Element rstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
        rstyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantStyle");
        Element ristyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
        ristyle.setAttribute("id", "restaurantIcon");
        Element ricon = doc.createElement("Icon");
        Element riconhref = doc.createElement("href");
        riconhref
                .appendChild(doc
                        .createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon63.png"));
        rstyle.appendChild(ristyle);
        ricon.appendChild(riconhref);
        ristyle.appendChild(ricon);
        dnode.appendChild(rstyle);
        Element bstyle = doc.createElement("Style");
        bstyle.setAttribute("id", "barStyle");
        Element bistyle = doc.createElement("IconStyle");
        bistyle.setAttribute("id", "barIcon");
        Element bicon = doc.createElement("Icon");
        Element biconhref = doc.createElement("href");
        biconhref
                .appendChild(doc
                        .createTextNode("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon27.png"));
        bstyle.appendChild(bistyle);
        bicon.appendChild(biconhref);
        bistyle.appendChild(bicon);
        dnode.appendChild(bstyle);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM markers");
        while (rs.next()) {
            KML.id = rs.getInt("id");
            KML.name = rs.getString("name");
            KML.address = rs.getString("address");
            KML.lat = rs.getFloat("lat");
            KML.lng = rs.getFloat("lng");
            KML.type = rs.getString("type");
            Element placemark = doc.createElement("Placemark");
            dnode.appendChild(placemark);
            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.name));
            placemark.appendChild(name);
            Element descrip = doc.createElement("description");
            descrip.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.address));
            placemark.appendChild(descrip);
            Element styleUrl = doc.createElement("styleUrl");
            styleUrl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("#" + KML.type
                    + "Style"));
            placemark.appendChild(styleUrl);
            Element point = doc.createElement("Point");
            Element coordinates = doc.createElement("coordinates");
            coordinates.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(KML.lng + ","
                    + KML.lat));
            point.appendChild(coordinates);
            placemark.appendChild(point);
        }
        Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
        Result dest = new StreamResult(new File("c:/PlaceMarkers.kml"));
        aTransformer.transform(src, dest);
        System.out.println("Completed.....");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You should analize your issues a little bit before asking for help. The error that you are getting is not related with KML and will not be corrected by a KML API.

Comment: Surrounding the entirety of the code in a try/catch is hardly helpful though the output of the message should be (is) telling you what's going on. I'd suggest either making the try/catch more targetted or use e.printStackTrace() in the catch block to tell you exactly where the code is failing. Then work from there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Java API for KML](https://code.google.com/p/javaapiforkml/)
The objective of the Java API for KML is to provide Java interfaces for easy access to KML (Keyhole Markup Language) data.

The main goal of the Java API for KML (JAK) is to provide automatically generated full reference implementation of the KML object model defined by OGC’s KML standard and Google’s GX extensions. It is an object orientated API that enables the convenient and easy use of KML in existing Java environments.

Comment: yes, JAK requires you add a new jar to your CLASSPATH with the appropriate imports but your Java code will be simpler and shorter doing the same thing.